# Isekai about a girl who is reincarnated and knows she will be the villainess in the future

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It is about a girl who is reincarnated into a young girl and she knows she will be the villainess in the future. This is a webtoon. I think the girl has brown hair and later on she has plant magic. There is no talks of inheritance since her dad is very much alive, but i think the dad died in the original story line.

She has to be engaged to the male lead (black hair) but she's smart enough to know the male lead does not like her. She told the male lead it will be a win-win situation for them if they get engaged so they won't have to keep meeting other prospects.

I think their fathers have some sort of connection with each other. Afterwards, the male lead and the young girl started hanging out more often. They are still kids at this point.

Comment: I didn't know this was [such a genre](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/villainess).

Comment: Was this black&white manga or a full color webtoon? Do you remember when you read it, and about how many chapters there were?

Comment: im not sure how to edit this. i think the female lead's hair color is brown and this is a webtoon. pretty sure it is korean. ty all

Comment: @JackDang: There's an [edit] link on the question if you're logged into the account you used to create it. :) Others can edit it too, but it requires a bit more rep.

Comment: How certain are you on the details?  If the win-win situation isn't about meeting prospects and if being a kid means the girl is still to young to inherit her estate, then "The Villainess Lives Again" might be what you are looking for.  The girl is 18, and the male lead older than that.

Comment: @JackDang Do you remember any other details? Did the male lead have an aristocratic rank, or is he a prince, or a high-ranking military leader, or just a commoner? They get married to avoid other engagements; do you recall any specific engagements they want to avoid? E.g. the villainess's sister and the male lead? Was there an empress involved? Or other political power struggle? Do you remember any specifics of what the plant magic was used for?

Comment: @Jack Dang - If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

I think the isekai is [My next life as a Villainess: all Routes Lead to Doom!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Next_Life_as_a_Villainess:_All_Routes_Lead_to_Doom)

The only thing that doesn't match is the the hair of the male because he has blond hair and their fathers, in the series these two characters are not presented and they know each other at the beginning.

Comment: it is not this one but i read it and enjoyed it very much

Answer (score 3):

Could this be ***[It Seems Like I Got Reincarnated Into The World of a Yandere Otome Game](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120363/Yandere-kei_Otome_Game_no_Sekai_ni_Tensei_shiteshimatta_you_desu)***...?

From MyAnimeList:

> Déjà vu—Licorice Radiata knows it all too well. Throughout her entire life, she has been plagued by vague feelings that everything has previously already come to pass. Then, after seeing a portrait of her fiancé Wolfgang Eisenhut, a surge of memories flow into her head: she is the rival character of a yandere otome game, and Wolfgang is one of the many "target" characters.
>
> In the original storyline, Licorice was the jealous rival, committing terrible and violent acts, and even in the heroine's good ending, she would die a bloody death. Mustering her courage and scattered recollections, Licorice is ready to do whatever it takes to avoid such a dreadful downfall, but can she prevent Wolfgang from becoming a yandere? It is not that simple to alter the course of fate, and she may have to accept that one's nature is not so easily changed.

The protagonist is Lycoris Radiata, the brown-haired daughter of a duke. When she's ten years old, her father shows her a portrait of Wolfgang Eisenhut, the black-haired son of another duke.

The moment Lycoris sees the image of Wolfgang's face, her mind is flooded with memories from a previous life. She was realises that she was an officer worker in another world, who was killed in a traffic accident, and that she's been reincarnated into the world of an otome game she used to play. Her character, Lycoris, is due to become the rival of the heroine, and Wolfgang is due to become her fiancée, and then possibly kill her in one of the game's routes.

Their fathers want them to become engaged to one another, and eventually produce heirs for both families, and so Lycoris and Wolfgang are formally introduced, in person. As soon as they're left alone together though, Wolfgang makes it clear to Lycoris that he isn't attracted to her, and that he doesn't want her to "misunderstand" her position as his fiancée.

Lycoris suggests that they both agree to the engagement for the time being, so their fathers won't keep bringing the subject up, but then later break it off when Wolfgang meets a girl he actually wants to marry. As the story progresses though, they both develop stronger feelings for one another, and both later attend the same magic academy.

[image]